# Can I put two elements in the same cell of a grid, and only show one at a time?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I would like to, based on state, display one or the other control assigned to a grid's cell, such as:

```
<Button x:Name="btnBla" Grid.Row=42 Grid.Column=7></Button>
<TextBlock x:Name="txtblockOh" Grid.Row=42 Grid.Column=7 IsEnabled="false"></TextBlock>
```

...and then in the code-behind:

```
btnBla.IsEnabled = someBool;
txtblockOh.IsEnabled = ! btnBla.IsEnabled;
```

Is this the preferred method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to "Show" one at a time as your question states, you should change the `Visibility` property insted of the IsEnabled.

You CAN do it in code, although I always recommend against manipulating UI elements in code (be it WPF, Silverlight or WinRT), all XAML-based technologies are much friendlier if you use the MVVM way of thinking.

Comment: Ah, yes, Visibility, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can be look at this page: [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.visibility.aspx)